# HttpWebRequest - brackets not allowed in POST

Tags: .net, http, httpwebrequest

EDIT: I was using copied code from another project which was overly complicated... Luckily weekend isn't far away.

********Original question****************************

I'm currently wrapping an external SMS-gateway API for internal use - the external API requires that a message to multiple recipients uses the following syntax:

http://(smsgateway)/?username=foo&pass=bar&from=myName&recipient[]=4512345678&recipient[]=4587654321&...

That works fine for GET requests but I would rather POST to the gateway to avoid issues with very large URL's generated. even though HTTP 1.1 does not explicitly constrain clients from sending requests with very long URLs to a server.

The issue here is that I'm not allowed to use a form parameter name containing brackets if I use HttpWebRequest in .NET 4. I get the following error: 'Specified value has invalid HTTP Header characters'

My question is: I haven't been able to find anything in the HTTP 1.1 specification regarding invalid characters in form parameter names so why am I not allowed to use a form parameter name called 'recipients[]'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you sending the POST request? HTTP does not care about the POST "form parameters", because they are sent in the request body (with appropriate content encoding).

Comment: The error occurs when adding to the form collection: webRequest.Headers.Add("recipients[]", "somevalue");

Comment: That is not how POST requests work - form parameters are not sent in the request headers. They are sent in the request body.

Comment: Here is what a quick google search found, notice how postData is being sent: http://www.netomatix.com/httppostdata.aspx

Comment: I was using code from another project but after a bit of reengineering inspired by your example everything works like a charm. Nice one - thank you